# Test to see if each file in a folder is a jpeg

Tags: c#, file-io, jpeg

I want to have code that does the following:

```
foreach(File in Directory)
{
  test to see if the file is a jpeg
}
```

but am unfamiliar with how to read from files. How do I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332451/c-sharp-list-all-files-and-directories-in-a-directory-subdirectories --- does this answer your quesiton?

Comment: If Jonathans answer isn't what your after, directory.getfiles().All(x => x.fileextension == jpg)); syntax maybe slightly off here

Comment: Do you want to know if it's a valid jpeg file, or just that it has a jpeg extension?

Comment: I guess perhaps a better way of explaining it would be: `foreach(jpg in Directory){//Do something}` 

It should be fine just checking for a jpeg extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're targetting .NET 4 [Directory.EnumerateFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571.aspx) may be more efficient, especially for larger directories. If not, you can replace `EnumerateFiles` with `GetFiles` below.

```
//add all the extensions you want to filter to this array
string[] ext = { "*.jpg", "*.jpeg", "*.jiff"  };
var fPaths = ext.SelectMany(e => Directory.EnumerateFiles(myDir, e, SearchOption.AllDirectories)).ToList();
```

Once you have a list of files with the correct extension, you can check if the file is actually a JPEG (as opposed to just being renamed `.jpg`) by using on of the two different methods mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/772492/187697). (From that post)

```
static bool HasJpegHeader(string filename)
{
    using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open)))
    {
        UInt16 soi = br.ReadUInt16();  // Start of Image (SOI) marker (FFD8)
        UInt16 jfif = br.ReadUInt16(); // JFIF marker (FFE0)

        return soi == 0xd8ff && jfif == 0xe0ff;
    }
}
```

Or a more accurate, but slower, method

```
static bool IsJpegImage(string filename)
{
    try
    {
        System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(filename);

        // Two image formats can be compared using the Equals method
        // See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.imageformat.aspx
        //
        return img.RawFormat.Equals(System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
    catch (OutOfMemoryException)
    {
        // Image.FromFile throws an OutOfMemoryException 
        // if the file does not have a valid image format or
        // GDI+ does not support the pixel format of the file.
        //
        return false;
    }
}
```

If there's a chance that you have JPEG files that don't have the correct extension then you'll have to loop through all files within the directories (use `*.*` as the filter) and perform one of the two methods above on them.

Comment: After much testing it looks like yours is the answer that I needed. Thanks for your time and effort in this. Here is what I ended up with:

`var fPaths = ext.SelectMany(a => Directory.EnumerateFiles(filepath, a, SearchOption.AllDirectories)).ToList();
            for (int i = 0; i < fPaths.Count; i++)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(fPaths[i]);
            }`

Answer (score 2):

Why not use [`Directory.GetFiles()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx) to get only the ones you want?  This code will return all `.jpg` and `.jpeg` files.

```
Directory.GetFiles("Content/img/", ".jp?g");
```

Comment: Actually, it will return an array of strings containing a complete path for each file in the folder.

Comment: And in theory the following are also jpeg files: .jpe, .jfif and .jif

Comment: That just tells you if they have a likely extension. It doesn't verify the files' format.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to know is which files have jpeg extensions, I would do this:

```
HashSet<string> JpegExtensions = 
    new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
        { ".jpg", ".jpe", ".jpeg", ".jfi", ".jfif" }; // add others as necessary

foreach(var fname in Directory.EnumerateFiles(pathname))
{
    if (JpegExtensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(fname))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(fname); // do something with the file
    }
}
```